# Time dummies to correct trend non-stationary data

Tags: time-series, stationarity, trend, categorical-encoding

If a time series data has no unit root, but has a time trend, can one include time dummy instead of time trend to remove non-stationarity?

The main reason is that I need to include time dummies, but I don't want to include both time dummies and time trend.

Comment: *a time series data has no unit root (i.e. difference stationary)* is contradictory. Either the series has a unit root and is difference stationary, or it does not and is stationary as is (without differencing).

Comment: Oh sorry. I just edited the question. The main concern is still the same though.